# Specify different get/set types on Vue reactivity types

Tags: typescript, vue.js

with [Variant Accessors](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/42425) released in [TS 5.1](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-1.html#unrelated-types-for-getters-and-setters) I would love to be able to create composables like this one

```
export function useRouteQueryParam(param: MaybeRef<string>): WritableComputedRef<string | null>
export function useRouteQueryParam(param: MaybeRef<string>, defaultValue: string): WritableComputedRef<string>
export function useRouteQueryParam(param: MaybeRef<string>, defaultValue?: string): WritableComputedRef<string | null> {
  const paramRef = ref(param)
  const route = useRoute()
  const router = useRouter()

  return computed({
    get() {
      const [value] = asArray(route.query[paramRef.value])

      return value ?? defaultValue ?? null
    },
    set(value) {
      const query = { ...route.query, [paramRef.value]: value }
      router.push({ query })
    },
  })
}
```

which in theory could use variant accessors for the `WritableComputedRef` when the caller provides a `defaultValue`. The get would always return `string`, but the set should still accept `string | null`. However, because the syntax for `WritableComputedRef` only takes a single `T` I'm guessing this isn't possible yet?

Comment: Not directly related to TS features. I doubt it's possible, just because WritableComputedRef  works the way it works. You could come up with your own type but there's a risk it's incompatible with places where this computed is used

Answer (score 0):

https://tsplay.dev/wea0ew

```
import { computed, WritableComputedRef, DebuggerOptions, ComputedGetter, ComputedSetter } from 'vue'

declare class GetSet<G, S> {
    get value(): G;
    set value(value: G | S)
}
interface BiPutedRef<G, S> extends Omit<WritableComputedRef<G>, 'value'>, GetSet<G, S> { }
interface BiPutedOptions<G, S> {
    get: ComputedGetter<G>;
    set: ComputedSetter<G | S>;
}

export function biputed<G, S = never>(
    options: BiPutedOptions<G, S>,
    debugOptions?: DebuggerOptions,
): BiPutedRef<G, Exclude<S, G>> {
    return computed(options, debugOptions);
}

;; let r = biputed({
    // ^?
    // let r: BiPutedRef<number, string>
    get() { return 123 },
    set(v: number | string) { }
})

let a = r.value
//  ^?
// let a: number

r.value = 'foo';
// ok
```